# What control is the best to edit Yes/No properties?

Tags: buttons, controls, checkboxes

What do you think? I have a little window with one content control. What is the best control to edit a Yes/No value? At the beginning i used a combobox,now a radiobutton. Maybe is a checkbox better? Depending on usability issues, what would you use? What is your opinion on that?

If it is the radio button, do you can provide an example of style so that this radio button looks pretty?

Comment: Ziggy. I have read your question trice and it is Klington to me. Perhaps you mean "Pros and cons of controls to select 'Yes/No' options". It is unclear what you are asking. While I'm sure it is clear to you, please consider the fact that not everyone know your case like you do. Please revise your question.

Comment: i think i get you, and have answered accordingly, however, for future reference you should ask for conclusive answers with evidence to back them up, not opinions, also, as this is a UX site, the questions often transcend the development stack, i.e. whether you are using LAMP, .NET or developing a physical interface, the same UX question may apply. If your question seems to rely heavily on a particular development stack (this one doesn't), you may want a different Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a yes/no selection a checkbox is best, or something that functions like a checkbox.

For example, stack overflow votes up or down, click once to vote, and again to undo.

Another example is a facebook like, click once to like, then again to unlike.

This is a very common UI pattern for yes/no or other Boolean choices and transcends the development stack. It is common amongst physical interfaces as well as software ones.

Radio buttons require finding two targets to toggle, whereas a checkbox doesn't.

As for pretty, with javascript and css you can make your yes/no look like anything. Again, this site, what is essentially a checkbox is made to look like a highlighted up or down arrow.